# Restlet web.xml config for new component

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

I have set up an App Engine Restlet Project (v 2.2.2) which returns a html or json response (web or android client) and different data from a db for different users. I have implemented HTTP basic authentication. It all works quite well.

my basic setup atm (I have simplified it ofc):

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ChallengeAuthenticator authenticatior;
    private ChallengeAuthenticator createAuthenticator() {...}
    public boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {...}

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        this.authenticatior = createAuthenticator();        
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        router.attachDefault(MyRestlet.class);
        authenticatior.setNext(router);
        return authenticatior;
    }
```

**MyRestlet.java**

```
public class MyRestlet extends ServerResource {

        @Get("json")
        public Representation getJSON() {
            MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
                if (!app.authenticate(getRequest(), getResponse())) {
                    // Not authenticated
                    return null;
                }
                else {
                    return data;     
                }

        @Get("html")
        public String getHTML() {...}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml ...>
<display-name>MyName</display-name>  

<context-param>
<param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
<param-value>x.MyApplication</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyRestlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyRestlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now I want to add encryption and created keys/certificates. My guide was this [tutorial](http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/core/security/https). I wanted to try to add a simple component first, stay with HTTP and change the port to 8183 as done in this [tutorial](http://restlet.com/learn/tutorial/2.2/#/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/319-restlet.html). I have now played around quite a bit and cannot seem to get my component to work. So my question is: Where would I put this main-Method (the following code is taken from the tutorial)? Into which class should I insert it or should I create a seperate server-class and what exactly would the required changes to the web.xml look like (I did not find much concerning this and I suspect that this is the central problem)? Any help is appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a new Restlet component and add a HTTP server connector to it
    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

    // Then attach it to the local host
    component.getDefaultHost().attach("/trace", Part05.class);

    // Now, let's start the component!
    // Note that the HTTP server connector is also automatically started.
    component.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was trying to convert a JavaSE RESTLET app to a JavaEE app. What I understood from the "Restlet in Action" book, Pg 72, is that we dont need to attach a server to the component as Servlet engine handles the incoming HTTP and HTTPS requests.

The tutorial also points to the component file an an INIT-PARAM or param-name in your web.xml. However for me, none of above 2 changes are working.

If I point to the application class as an INIT-PARAM and not use a HTTP connector as suggested in the book, i am able to access the APIs but not able to make any calls from the client class as I get the below error -

*WARNING: The protocol used by this request is not declared in the list of client connectors. (HTTP/1.1). In case you are using an instance of the Component class, check its "clients" property.
Not Found (404) - The server has not found anything matching the request URI*

Hope these info help you in some way

---

**EDIT**

I found the solution to the above problem -
I had to add the below piece of code

```
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.restlet.clients</param-name>
            <param-value>HTTP HTTPS FILE</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

Also for your problem, you need to configure the Component via an XML. Below URLs will give more info -

http://restlet.com/learn/javadocs/2.1/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html
http://restlet.com/learn/javadocs/2.1/jee/api/org/restlet/Component.html?is-external=true

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly confusing, probably because of the path you have taken.

Your original plan creates a RESTlet web application, complete with web.xml to run inside a container, such as GAE, Jetty or Tomcat.

What you're proposing creates a component and starts a stand alone server (it starts an internal instance of Jetty). This won't work on Google App Engine.

You should continue with the web.xml approach and configure GAE to serve over https.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#https and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs for configuration instructions.

Also, another tip: return 403 status when something attempts to access a resource without authorisation.